# How can I create 50,000+ bitcoin addresses in my wallet?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, address-generation

How can I create 50,000+ bitcoin addresses in my wallet?

I will need more than 50,000+ addresses in my main wallet. I use Bitcoin Armory, Bitcoin-Qt and I'm just trying out Blockchain.info.

Is it possible to generate 50,000+ addresses in my wallet? If I use bBitcoin-Qt  or Armory I can create addresses manually, but I need something to automate this system.

Is it possible? Is there some API for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have Bitcoin-Qt generate 50k addresses by starting it with the parameter `-keypool=50000`.

They will not all be visible in the client interface, most will be just hidden as unused backup addresses, but they will all be stored in your `wallet.dat`.

Answer (score 1):

The Satoshi Bitcoin client (`bitcoin-qt` or `bitcoind`) has an [RPC API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29) which is the most common way to interact with it programatically.  You can use the `getnewaddress` command to create as many addresses as you like.  I know of no reason why it shouldn't be able to handle 50,000 or more.

Comment: Memory leaks (of temporary used memory)?

Comment: @Peter: I'm not aware of the Satoshi client having such bugs, are you?